# Terminal profile doesn't list all available fonts

Tags: command-line, gnome, fonts, gnome-terminal

my GNOME Terminal profile let me choose only mono fonts and Courier.
I'm trying to use Source Code Pro font on my ubuntu terminal. I've installed it successfully, in ~/.fonts, and it shows on every other program, as all the other fonts. But on Terminal profile only some fonts are listed.

How do I use Source Code Pro font, and other fonts, on GNOME Terminal?

Here is an info about my Ubuntu 14.04, tell me if you need anymore:

Linux dev 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Silly question, but how exactly did you install it? I tried it from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecodepro.adobe/files/latest/download?source=typ_redirect, copied the ttf to `~/.fonts` works immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Just force to update the font cache:

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```